# How can I stack two views on top of each other?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have 3 views, playView, gameView and timeView.

gameView is the top left block. timeView is the bottom left block and playView is the right block.

This is a photo of the program I need to remake.

[image]

How should I stack those two views on top of each other. And then the other view on the right of those two.

As you can see the bottom left block is a bit bigger than the top left block.

I've tried using GridLayout and BoxLayout but none of those seem to work.

This is what I've tried. It does work but the size is the same of the two left blocks.

```
    public void setGameView(GameView gameView, PlayView playView,TimeView timeView) {
    this.gameView = gameView;
    this.playView = playView;
    this.timeView = timeView;

    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    subPanel.add(gameView);
    subPanel.add(timeView);

    this.add(playView, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
  }
```

I would like to get the same result as the photo. If someone can steer me the right way. What layout should I use?

Comment: @camickr I edited the image. I want those two blocks on the left like in the image, but I need those two blocks to have different sizes (also like in the image).

Comment: Either the GridBagLayout or BoxLayout should work. Both of these layout managers will respect the `preferred size` of each component. Then if there is extra space that space will be allocated to each component. This is done automatically by the BoxLayout. For the GridBagLayout you need to specify the weighty constraint of the GridBagConstraints. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more info on constraints. So if it doesn't work the problem is with your GameView and PlayView classes.

Comment: @camickr I set the size of each component so that it all fits good, but when I use BoxLayout I am not able to place two components on the left side and one above the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set the size

You should not set the size.

If you are using components on panels, then each layout manager will determine the preferred size.

If you are doing custom painting then your component should implement the `getPreferredSize()` method so layout managers can do their job.

> when I use BoxLayout I am not able to place two components on the left side

```
JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
subPanel.add(gameView);
subPanel.add(timeView);
```

You are setting the wrong panel to use the BoxLayout.

The code should be:

```
//JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
subPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(subPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Or an easier way is to sue the `Box` class:

```
Box subpanel = Box.createVerticalBox();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `BorderLayout`, if no element is occupying a particular border, the panel in the `CENTER` will extend to the edge of the parent.

In your case, your `gamePanel` should be placed in the `CENTER`, not the `EAST`.  Your subpanel should remain where it is in the `WEST`.

Comment: I edited the image. I want those two blocks on the left like in the image, but I need those two blocks to have different sizes (also like in the image).